# Is it possible to embed the macOS color picker in a view?

Tags: macos, nsview, color-picker

I really love the macOS color picker and want to let my users use it in my app. However, I don't like how it pops up above the UI and stays there even if nothing's selected. **Is there any way to embed it within a `NSView` and remove it after I'm done with it?**

Comment: I have never seen that anywhere in macOS with the system's color picker. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, it involved getting the NSColorPanel and manually traversing its view hierarchy, essentially manually grabbing the view, removing it, and placing it in my app